# Zurb Foundation Modal Positioning Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, zurb-foundation

I am currently working on a website where the reveal modal window when I am at the top of the page works perfectly if I scroll down the page the modal exceeds the window size. Like so

[image]

I believe that the modal is determining that since I am scrolled the window? size is larger and determines the appropriate position to place the modal which is not in the center of the screen.

The position added to the modal is

```
top: 511px;
```

Is there a way to get around this to prevent it from exceeding the window size?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to prevent this from happening by adding

```
html { 
  overflow: hidden;
}
```